# Laravel package facade

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have create facade for my package by following the tutorial (https://github.com/orangehill/Laravel-Workbench-Walkthrough#package-facade-generation).

Now I have the facade working with all the function store on package main class.

E.g:

```
<?php namespace Orangehill\Walkthrough;

class Walkthrough {

    public static function hello(){
        return "What's up Zagreb!";
    }

   .....

}
```

I am able call to the function in the main class file with something like this:

```
Walkthrough::hello();
Walkthrough::hello2();
Walkthrough::hello3();
....
```

The problem is now my main class file has grown huge with lots of functions in it. How can I separate it into multiple class files? After separating, how can I have the facade able to link to it under the same facade name?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like you followed the guide at all. Your "facade" class doesn't even extend Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.

Comment: @Andreas That example code is the package main class where I put all the function in. If you scroll up that guide, you will get what I mean. Do you know how to separate that huge class into multiple class? Thank you.